# grails renderErrors without outputting the fully qualified field name

Tags: grails

I'm adding a custom error

```
trip.errors.rejectValue('driver','Driver already on a trip at this time.')
```

When I output the error in a view....

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${trip}" field="driver">
    <g:renderErrors bean="${trip}" field="driver" as="list" />
</g:hasErrors>
```

....a fully qualified field path gets appended to it.

```
"Driver already on a trip at this time. org.heidelberg.Trip.driver"
```

How can I get rid of the `org.heidleberg.Trip.driver` part that is applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method calling is incorrect. 
Try this -

```
trip.errors.rejectValue('driver',null,'Driver already on a trip at this time.')
```

it should work fine. 
The correct method signature of rejectValue method is

```
void rejectValue(String field, String errorCode, String defaultMessage
```

Cheers!!